# Calling a HTTP anonymous web service from a HTTPS IIS8 web site error

Tags: web-services, wcf

I am running an asp.net application within an IIS8 HTTPS web site.
The application is trying to access a HTTP web service but receives
this error on calling.

Error: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.

The call to the web service works from my development pc as it's running
locally as http.

I'm wondering if this is an IIS setting change or a web.config change or if HTTP
requests are allowed at all within a HTTPS site?

The web service being called is setup in the web.config as:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="APPO_LookupSoap">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>          
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://netdocs.xxxxxxxx.co.uk/TroposNetDocsIntegration/APPO_Lookup.asmx" 
  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="APPO_LookupSoap" 
  contract="RM_WebService.APPO_LookupSoap" name="APPO_LookupSoap" />
</client>

</system.serviceModel>
```